How to Write a Pandas DataFrame to CSV With Strings Quoted and Integers/Empty Cells Unaltered Without Adding Escape Characters for Commas?
I am working on a Python script to write a DataFrame to a CSV file. My goal is to:

Enclose all string values in double quotes (").
Keep numeric values unchanged (no quotes).
Leave empty cells as they are.

Here’s the code I’m currently using:
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'col1': ['hello, world', 'test', '', None], 'col2': [123, 456, 789, None]}
report_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Add quotes only to non-numeric, non-empty cells
for col in report_df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'bool']).columns:
    report_df[col] = report_df[col].apply(
        lambda x: f'"{x}"' if pd.notnull(x) and str(x).strip() != "" else ""
    )

# Write to CSV without quoting numeric columns
report_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=" ")


The problem I face is that when a string contains a comma (e.g., "hello, world"), the CSV writer adds an escape character () before the comma, resulting in an output like this:
"hello\, world",123
"test",456
,789
,

I want to avoid this behavior and have the output directly include the comma within the quoted string, like so:
"hello, world",123
"test",456
,789
,

I have tried csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL: When I set quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, quotes are only added around strings containing commas, and other strings are left unquoted, which does not meet my requirement.
Custom Logic Issue: When combining csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL with my custom logic to quote all strings, the resulting output has extra double quotes, like:
""""hello, world""""
""""test""""
,

I need a solution that:

Quotes all string values consistently, including those with commas, without adding escape characters or extra quotes.
Keeps numeric values and empty cells unaltered.


Did you find useful one of the answer or you found a better solution?

You can use escapechar="\\"
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = {'col1': ['hello, world', 'test', '', None], 'col2': [123, 456, 789, None]}
report_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

report_df.to_csv(
    "output.csv", 
    index=False, 
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
    escapechar="\\",  
    float_format='%.0f'  
)

files.download('output.csv')

CSV output
col1,col2
"hello, world",123
test,456
,789
,


I have tried QUOTE_MINIMAL but it only added quotes to strings which have comma in the values.
I wanted to add double quotes to all strings, not just strings which have comma .
In the example i wanted the test also with in double quotes like below just like below.
col1,col2
"hello, world",123
"test",456
,789
,

If you don't mind to save the file in another format, one solution would be to use pickle format:
report_df.to_pickle('file.pkl')
report_df2 = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')

Or json format if you prefer to "see" the data:
report_df.to_json('file.json')
report_df2 = pd.read_json('file.json')

